# A Curious Recipe

Tags: cipher

Little Red Riding Hood received this odd recipe from her grandmother.

> Hello. Here's a cake recipe you might enjoy!
>
> ***Orange cake:*** *(serves 4)*
>
> **Ingredients:**
>   - 111 cups caster sugar
>   - 112mL orange flavoring
>   - 216 oranges
>   - 102 eggs
>   - 83 cups milk
>   - 104g orange icing
>   - 46g vanilla extract
>   - 64 cups self-raising flour
>   - 202 orange rinds
>   - 87g butter
>   - 110 cups almond meal
>   - 100mL orange juice
>
> **Method:**
>   Put the butter in the bowl. Put the caster sugar in the bowl. Put half the oranges in the bowl. Put the eggs in the bowl. Pour the vanilla extract in the bowl. Put half the self-raising flour in the bowl. Pour the milk in the bowl. Put half the orange rinds in the bowl. Put the almond meal in the bowl. Pour the orange juice in the bowl. Put the rest of the self-raising flour in the bowl. Put the icing in the bowl. Put the rest of the orange rinds in the bowl. Put the rest of the oranges in the bowl. Pour the orange flavoring in the bowl. Stir vigorously. Eat.

However, something seems a little off to Little Red Riding Hood...
***Can you discover the secret message?***

Comment: I think the 216 oranges alone would serve way more than 4.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is:

> **"Wolf. Send help"**

The explanation is:

> Interpret the (full or halfed) quantities of ingredients as ASCII code numbers

Here is the full translation:

- W = 87g = Put the butter in the bowl.
- o = 111 cups = Put the caster sugar in the bowl.
- l = 108 = Put half the oranges in the bowl.
- f = 102 = Put the eggs in the bowl.
- full stop = 46g = Pour the vanilla extract in the bowl.
- blank = 32 cups = Put half the self-raising flour in the bowl.
- S = 83 cups = Pour the milk in the bowl.
- e = 101 = Put half the orange rinds in the bowl.
- n = 110 cups = Put the almond meal in the bowl.
- d = 100mL = Pour the orange juice in the bowl.
- blank  = 32 cups = Put the rest of the self-raising flour in the bowl.
- h = 104g = Put the icing in the bowl.
- e = 101 = Put the rest of the orange rinds in the bowl.
- l = 108 = Put the rest of the oranges in the bowl.
- p = 112mL = Pour the orange flavoring in the bowl.

Comment: Reminds me of [Chef](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Chef)...

Comment: @Geobits That's exactly what I thought of when I saw the puzzle. Actually, it wouldn't take much modification to make it a valid `Chef` program that outputs the answer.